# What does == mean inside a NDArray?

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to get the median of a NDArray, so i have something like np.median(ndarray,axis=0)
My ndarray is something as below,

`boxes[current_nearest == cluster]`

What does the == mean? Afaik, ndarray[index] it to access the element at that index inside a ndarray.

Comment: It's used for masking/indexing. This way you select a sub-array. You can check the mask: `print(current_nearest == cluster)`.

Answer (score 0):

@rpoleski, alright thanks,

`clusters[cluster] = np.median(boxes[current_nearest == cluster], axis=0)`

does it mean only the boxes[True] will be used in finding the median?

Comment: Yes. Try googling array indexing or masking to see how it works. You can do, e.g., `b = (a < 5)`, `c = (a > -10)`, `print(a[b & c])`.